# При добавлении пакета в код Go не получается скомпилировать программу

Tags: golang

Написал пару строк кода на Go, а точнее вот эти строки:

```golang
package main

func main () {
    println("hello world")
}
```

Все сработало: и `go run`, и `go build`, но стоило добавить пару строк из примера выдает: `expected 'package', found 'EOF'`, дополнения были следующими:

```golang
package main 

import (
    "fmt"   
)

func main () {
    println("hello world")
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы добавляете пакет который не используете?

Answer (score 2):

для того чтобы этот код корректно собрался в Go надо написать например так

```
package main 
import (
      "fmt"   
       )
func main (){
fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

или так

```
package main 
import (
     _ "fmt"   
   )
func main (){
   println("hello world")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Oшибка `expected: pacakge, found EOF` может возникнуть только если файл пустой или [полностью состоит из комментариев](https://play.golang.org/p/_NUK1gtAJoS) или пробельных символов.

Скорее всего Вы пытаетесь скомпилировать какой-то другой пакет, а не тот, что у Вас в вопросе. Или забыли сохранить изменения, после очистки файла и сохранения его чистым.